# AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL

Tags: c++, data-structures, stack, queue

I am getting this error when I use `st.pop() in following code in leetcode:

```
AddressSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
=================================================================
==31==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address (pc 0x0000003a1925 bp 0x7ffd7b62dce0 sp 0x7ffd7b62dcd0 T0)
==31==The signal is caused by a READ memory access.
==31==Hint: this fault was caused by a dereference of a high value address (see register values below).  Dissassemble the provided pc to learn which register was used.
    #8 0x7f3d81a1e0b2  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2)
AddressSanitizer can not provide additional info.
==31==ABORTING
```

The code is as follows:

```
class Solution {
public:
    string removeOuterParentheses(string S) {
        stack<char> st;
        int count=0;
        string ns;
        for(int i=0;i<S.size();i++)
        {
            if(S[i] == 40 && count++ > 0)
            {
                st.push(S[i]);
                ns+=S[i];
            }
            if(S[i] == 41 && count-- > 0)
            {
                st.pop();
                ns+=S[i];
            }
        }
        return ns;
    }
};
```

Comment: I guess the stack is empty when you call `st.pop()`. You can check that easily by adding some lines of code. Also [edit] and show the code that calls `removeOuterParentheses`

Comment: First, don't use magic numbers.  If you want to see if a character is a `'('`, then use `S[i] == '('`.  Second, what happens if your stack is empty when you `pop`?

Comment: Look at what happens if the input is `40, 41`. `count` is incremented, but nothing is pushed in the stack at the first iteration, ...

Comment: @Damien , I am intentionally not pushing the parenthesis for the first iteration as I was working on the problem - Remove Outermost Parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an input string `"(some text)"` your condition `S[i] == 40 && count++ > 0` will always evaluate to false. When `S[i]=='('` is true then `count++ > 0` is false as `count` gets incremented after the comparison. However, `count` gets incremented such that the second condition `S[i] == ')' && count-- > 0` will eventually be true. Then you hit `st.pop()`. As `st` is empty, it will cause a problem.

Also, if you fix your code, e.g. by writing `S[i] == 40 && ++count > 0`, **it won't remove parentheses as the name implies**.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for helping out. It was trying to pop an empty stack.

Error - `if(S[i] == 41 && count-- > 0)`

Correction - `if(S[i] == 41 && count-- > 1)`